# передать значение переменой в другое view

Tags: objective-c, ios

Есть QTableview и Detailview. Как мне из первого передать во второе значение переменной?
В qtableview я объявляю переменную `@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *coord;` и вписываю `#import "Detail2ViewController.h"`. Затем пишу

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Detail2ViewController *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detail"];
    NSString* coord = _sortedStates[indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"virable coord %@",coord); // сюда значение пришло, отправляем дальше
     }
```

В detailview опять объявляем её

```
    @interface Detail2ViewController : UIViewController{
    NSString *coord;}
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *state, *capital, *coord;
```

вписываем в detailview `NSLog(@"def %@",coord);` и видим что ничего не пришло - и вот вопрос, почему и как её передать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После присвоения переменной `coord` значение из масива, далее нужно объекту `detail` установить свойство `detail.coord = coord;` Вот пример кода:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    Detail2ViewController *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detail"];
    NSString* coord = _sortedStates[indexPath.row];
    detail.coord = coord;
    NSLog(@"virable coord %@",coord); 
 }
```